# Using a maximum principle to deduce regularity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an bounded domain and that $u \in C(0,T; H^{2}) \cap L^{2}(0,T; H^{3})$ where $T >0$.

Consider the PDE on $\Omega \times [0,T]$

$$ \partial_{t}u = a_{1}(x,t) \partial_{x}^{2}u + a_{2}(x,t)\partial_{x}u + a_{3}(x,t)u + a_{4}(x,t)u^{2} + a_{5}(x,t) ,$$ where $a_{1},...,a_{5} \in C(0,T; H^{1})$. It is straightforward to deduce that $\partial_{t}u \in C(0,T; L^{2}) \cap L^{2}(0,T; H^{1})$ from the above equation, thanks to the regularity on $u$. However, I want to show that $\partial_{t} u \in C(0,T; H^{1})$ so that I can use the 1D Sobolev embedding to conclude $u \in C^{1}([0,T] \times \mathbb{T})$.

I have seen an author mention in a remark that this would be possible in our setting by using a 'refined maximum principle argument'. However, I really don't know what such an argument would look like, nor have I seen a similar example before.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Somebody please correct me if I am wrong, but can't we say $u \in C(0,T; H^{2})$ just from the facts that $u \in L^{2}(0,T; H^{3})$ and $\partial_{t}u \in L^{2}(0,T; H^{1})$? (E.g. from Corollary 7.3 in the Infinite Dimensional Dynamical systems book by Robinson) And then thanks to the 1D sobolev embedding $\partial_{t}u \in C( [0,T] \times \Omega)$

Comment: I really don't get how you deduce $\partial_tu\in C([0,T]\times\Omega)$ from $\partial_tu\in L^2(0,T;H^1)$?

Comment: @leomonsaingeon I incorrectly applied a result, ignore me